# Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'text' with value '@string/Add Idea')

Tags: android, eclipse

I Googled all the day for this error and fixed all the XML with various answers provided in SO but still the issue persists.

I am working on eclipse on Mac machine and the code follows

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="35dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="@string/Add Idea"
     />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**Strings.XML**

```
<resources>   
    <string name="app_name">Idea Tracker</string>
    <string name="hello_world">Hello world!</string>
    <string name="menu_settings">Settings</string>
    <string name="button1">Add Idea</string>
</resources>
```

Though I added the required code in Strings.xml file but couldn't sort out why the issue persists.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `android:text` should be `@string/button1` since it's the identifier.

```
 <Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="35dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:text="@string/button1"
 />
```

Comment: Then I am getting error `[I18N] Hardcoded string "button1", should use @string resource`